# AppEngine: using Expando class in Django NonRel?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel, expando

I have an app using using Django Nonrel on AppEngine.

I'd like to use a dynamic model similar to WebApp's db.Expando class - is this possible? Is the Expando class exposed to the DNR layer?

Comment: Option 3 of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/7934577#7934577 applies to Django-nonrel in general.

Comment: @GagandeepSingh Thanks. 'from djangotoolbox.fields import DictField' was exactly what I was looking for. If you put that as an answer I'll tick it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DictField & [ListField](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/03/Updates-on-djangoappengine) from djangotoolbox to create dynamic models in Django-nonrel. For e.g.

```
from djangotoolbox.fields import DictField

class Image(models.Model):
    exif = DictField()
```

and,

```
class Post(models.Model):
    words = ListField(models.CharField(max_length=500))
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

See Option 3 of [Django dynamic model fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/7934577#7934577) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Django implements its own DB abstraction layer - it's not built on App Engine's db module. If django does not provide it itself, it's not available.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. Hence asking 'Is the Expando class exposed to the DNR layer?' in the question.

Comment: @nailer But that question doesn't make sense in the context: the expando class is not exposed, because it's not used. Django-nonrel does not use the App Engine db framework. It's not possible to expose it, because it's not _there_.