# Repeated fields in django models

Tags: django, model, field

I need to make a model that has 15 similar fields (let's call them `field_01`, `field_02`, `field_03`, etc.). I also need these fields to be easily available (e.g. to be able to do things like `obj.field_01`). Because I wanted to get something off the ground really quickly, I just created them the stupid way:

```
class M (models.Model):
    ....
    field_01 = models.NullBooleanField()
    field_02 = models.NullBooleanField()
    ....
```

I searched online for a better way to do this. Some people say use **`setattr`**, but as far as I could tell from reading and trying some stuff out, this adds attributes to an instance of a class, not the class itself, which means that when I try to attach a model form to this model, it will not see the fields added with `setattr`. Then I tried overriding the **`__new__`** function, which would allow me to add properties to a class before an instance of that class is created. But I wasn't able to figure out how to do this exactly.

So, what's a way to generate these fields without breaking South and model forms and without copy-paste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say definitively without a concrete example of what your doing, but generally, if you find yourself repeating a field, then it's a clear sign for a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship, instead:

**One-to-Many**

```
class Field(models.Model):
    m = models.ForeignKey(M, related_name='fields')
    field = models.NullBooleanField()
```

**Many-to-Many**

```
class Field(models.Model):
    field = models.NullBooleanField()

class M(models.Model):
    fields = models.ManyToManyField(Field)
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like this. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisPratt I am forever disappointed that you are not the actor Chris Pratt. At the small size your avatar looks like him, and the idea of an actor also having such high rep on a programming board seems cool.

Answer (score 1):

Django models have an `add_to_class` method you could (ab)use for monkey-patching models the way you  would like to do.

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    M.add_to_class('field_%s' % s, NullBooleanField())
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking to have an EAV style database. You should try a library instead of rolling your own. To that end, Django EAV looks pretty awesome. https://github.com/mvpdev/django-eav

To read more about pros and cons of a bunch of libraries to accomplish this check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7934577/884453