# Creating a new table on the fly

Tags: django

I am new to Django plotform. I am trying to write a program which basically accepts a post method. The content of incoming data is `storename, bookname, bookserial`. That part is already implemented and works well. When I post the content such as `storename=John's shopping center, bookname=Love is beatiful, bookserial=123`. It creates a table and save those things into a table. But, the thing is that I want to create not just only one table for each store. Because, I can have multiple `storename` and each store should have its own table. When I post the `storename` on the fly ,it should check `storename` and then if it's table is created already, the `bookname` and `bookserial` should be inserted its table. If not, a new table should be created and then the incoming data is inserted the new table. The new table name should be `storename` as well.So, as I said, I only need to learn how to create new tables on the fly part. Could you please help me how to do that, any comments and ideas is appreciated....

An example to make it clear,

```
Table-1=John's shopping center
    bookname=Love is beatiful
    bookserial=123

  Table-2= John's shopping center-2
     bookname=Time is important
     bookserial=456
```

So, the model is same for each shopping center but each of sopping center is a different table with the name of shopping center.

Comment: Are you sure you really need a new table each time? Do the "store" models differ extremely in schema between each one? Unfortunately you can't create models on the fly.

Comment: Yes, I really need  a new table for each time. Actually, the store model is same for each store but I need them on the different tables.

Answer (score 1):

In the traditional sense, it is not possible to dynamically create concrete tables on the fly in django. Models have to be registered as part of the application startup, so that the ORM can properly manage all the relations. Consider what would happen if you defined a new model that set up constraints or backrefs to other models. Those other models, being classes, have already been set up and are in memory. They can no longer go through their metaclass step to wire new relations. You could easily break things.

Your options are limited to either a solution involving a few tables that can dynamicaly describe different entities, or to use a nosql backend that does not care about schemas and will let you store anything at any time.

See this question and answer for details: [Django dynamic model fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/7934577#7934577)

The only way to have a concrete table on the fly is if you have the django app restart itself completely in response.