# django built-in support for MongoDB

Tags: django, nosql

I'm trying to find any information if official django is going to support any noSQL DBMS, especially MongoDB. I found a [fork of django 1.3](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-django-mongodb-engine/) the [django-nonrel](https://github.com/django-nonrel/django) (a fork of official django) and some other not very reliable projects (failures occur often, according to comments I found on the web). Is django going to support noSQL officially at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, there are **[other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/7934577#7934577)** to achieve your goals, besides going `noSQL`.

In short, if you just need dynamic fields, you have other options. I have an extensive writeup about them in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/7934577#7934577):

- [Entity–attribute–value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) ([Django-eav](https://github.com/mvpdev/django-eav))
- PostgreSQL [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html) ([Django-hstore](https://github.com/jordanm/django-hstore))
- Dynamic models [based on migrations](http://blip.tv/djangocon-europe-2011/wednesday-1415-will-hardy-5311186) ([Django-mutant](https://github.com/charettes/django-mutant))

Yes, that's not exactly what you've asked for, but that's all that we've currently got.

Comment: Hey, in my company, i had to create something to allows Dynamic Fields too, and we loved so much the postgres, so the HstoreFlattenfields was born...
https://github.com/multmeio/django-hstore-flattenfields

Check this out and help us!
We made some great advances... like Queries using the native ORM from django, like a ```Entity.objects.filter(my_dynamic_field__gte=10)```

Comment: @Luan, that's nice! I'll definitely look into it! Thanks!

Comment: @Luan, you definitely need a README file in your repository... :)

Comment: You are right, @Ivan, i have to do many things, i promise to you that until the next weekend all will be done. haha :D

Answer (score 2):

As you said, forked code is never the best alternative: changes take longer to get into the fork, it might break things... And even with `django-nonrel`, is not really Django as you loose things like model inheritance, M2M... basically anything that will need to do a `JOIN` query behind the scenes.

Is Django going to support NoSQL? As far as I know, there's no plans on the roadmap for doing so in the short run. According to [Russell Keith-Magee](https://github.com/freakboy3742) on his talk on [PyCon Russia 2013](http://www.slideshare.net/it-people/django-16-and-beyond?ref=http://pycon.ru/en/program/content/django-roadmap/), "NoSQL" is on the roadmap but in the long term, as well as SQLAlchemy. So if you wanna wait, is going to take a long time, I'm afraid.

Anyway, even if it's not ideal, you still can use Django but use something else as a ORM. Nothing stops you from use vanilla Django and something like MongoDB instead of Django ORM.