# django call admin.site.register from view

Tags: django, django-admin

I try to register model with the admin site from view.py, so model's admin interface would appear after I go to matching url. But when I go to matching url only model's name without reference appears, models instances doesn't display. It's necessary to register model from views.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from polls.models import Poll

def index(request):
    admin.site.register(Poll)
    return redirect('/admin')
```

Comment: Please, go through part two of the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/)

Comment: It's necessary to register model from views. I simplified problem actually I'm trying to create a dynamic models.

Comment: Dynamic models? Models are tied with a database, and they are not dynamic. What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: something like this
[DynamicModels](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/7934577#7934577) which is linked from the page you posted.

Comment: I have created dynamic models, I have problem only with admin interface as described in post.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Poll
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import clear_url_caches
from django.utils.importlib import import_module
from django.conf import settings

def index(request):
    admin.site.register(Poll)
    reload(import_module(settings.ROOT_URLCONF))
    clear_url_caches()
    return redirect('/admin')
```