# Use model.save data for Meta Tag in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views, metadata

Thank you for reading i am new to Django and
For my application it's a requirement to create a table for each client  to  store  his data. 
Each client  table has the same data so i made a Model for it.

But the table name is variable: 
i tried

Models.py

````
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True,)```

Model
```class Test(DatIm):

    class Meta(DataIm.Meta):
        db_table = DatIm.organisation```

in the view: 
 ```Test.objects.update_or_create(organisation=row['organisation'])```

but it doesnt  create the table  and gives errors. 



i  would expect to 
creates or get the table for organisation
insert model.save data in organisation Db 
I need for each organisation an table because a lot of data.
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic database tables in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126333/dynamic-database-tables-in-django)

Comment: No it’s not because I need duplicate tables