# How to dynamically set attributes to a class in models in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to dynamically set attribute to models. Here is the way I did it.

```
# models.py
class pwr(models.Model):



    # test info
    tester = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    test_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Test Date')
    test_summary = models.TextField(verbose_name='Test Summary')
    test_duration = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Test Duration')


    for i in xrange(2):
        ii = str(i)



        test_result = 'test_result_' + ii
        test_com = 'test_comment_' + ii
        bug_level = 'bug_level_' + ii
        bug_id = 'bug_id_' + ii
        bug_sum = 'bug_summary_' + ii
        exec (test_result + "= models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Result', \
        choices=(\
        ('Pass', 'P'), \
        ('Fail', 'F'), \
        ('Not Test', 'N/T'), \
        ('Not Avaliable', 'N/A'), \
        ('Reference', 'Ref'), \
        ('Warn', 'W')\
        ))")
        exec (test_com + "= models.CharField(max_length=100,  verbose_name='Comment',  blank=True)")
        exec (bug_level + "= models.CharField(max_length=100,  verbose_name='Bug Level',  blank=True, \
                            choices=(('1', '1:Blocker'), \
                            ('2', '2:Critical'), \
                            ('3', '3:Major'), \
                            ('4', '4:Normal'), \
                            ('5', '5:Enhancement')))")
        exec (bug_id + "= models.CharField(max_length=10,  verbose_name='Bug ID',  blank=True)")
        exec (bug_sum + "= models.CharField(max_length=100,  verbose_name='Bug Summary',  blank=True)")

# When I tried to use setattr here, no 'test_attribute' field is added to table pwr in database        
setattr(pwr, 'test_attribute', models.CharField(max_length=10,  verbose_name='test attr',  blank=True))
```

This seems really ugly.. Do you have any better solution for this?  Thanks!!!

Comment: You are looking for [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr).

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes, I've tried with setattr. But it seems not work in this case. Using it after class definition didn't work.

Comment: Then please post a small, self-contained example showing how you tried to do it and how it failed to work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/7934577#7934577

Comment: @BrenBarn Check my update in the code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set it dynamically with `setattr` because you are dealing with Python [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), not attributes. This is because of the order of events when the module is imported and Python class ans descriptors put together.

Naturally, you can still do this in superious dynamic language like Python. But the solution for the problem needs different approach

- You can use Python [metaclasses](http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/) and override `__new__`
- See [declared_](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html)attr in SQLAlchemy, its own way to solve this special case

Comment: Yes, I think I can use metaclass to solve this issue. Thanks!