# Generate Wagtail Field's using a FOR loop

Tags: python-3.x, wagtail

I am new to Wagtail and want to create several Field's in my models.py by iterating over a list of names like this ...

```
class HomePage(Page):
    myFields = [ ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock(classname="oneA")),('image', ImageChooserBlock()) ]

    mySections = ['sectionOne', 'sectionTwo', 'sectionThree']

    for mySection in mySections:
        mySection = StreamField(myFields,null=True,blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('sectionOne'), StreamFieldPanel('sectionTwo'), StreamFieldPanel('sectionThree'),
    ]
```

This produces an error message ...

> django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: HomePage has no field named 'sectionOne'

Is there a way of doing this, or do I have to declare each one individually like so:

```
sectionOne = StreamField(myFields,null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: You also might have a look at inline panels. http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/reference/pages/panels.html#inline-panels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because `mySection = StreamField(...)` is just repeatedly defining a field called `mySection` - there's no way for Python to know that you want to define a field with the name currently given *in* `mySection`.

I think the only way to achieve this is to set the fields up in a metaclass, which will almost certainly be more complex and less readable than just repeating the line. See [How to dynamically set attributes to a class in models in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066919/how-to-dynamically-set-attributes-to-a-class-in-models-in-django), [Dynamically create class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583620/dynamically-create-class-attributes)

Comment: Certainly setting up a meta-class would negate my goal of reducing code.  Thanks.