# Using dynamic models in Django framework

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I am currently using Django framework including its Models mechanism to abstract the database schema declaration and general db access, which is working fine for most scenarios.
However, my application also requires tables to be created and accessed dynamically during runtime, which as far as I can see, is not supported by Django out of the box. 
These tables usually have an identical structure, and can basically be abstracted by the same Model class, but Django doesn't let you change the underlying db_table of a certain model query, as it is declared on the Model class and not on the Manager.

My solution for this is to do this process whenever I need a new table to be created, populated and accessed:

- Create and populate the table using raw sql
- Add indexes to the table using raw sql
- When I need to access the table (using django queryset api), I declare a new type dynamically and return it as the model for the query, by using this code:

  ```
  table_name = # name of the table created by sql
  model_name = '%d_%s' % (connection.tenant.id, table_name)
  try:
      model = apps.get_registered_model('myapp', model_name)
      return model
  except LookupError:
      pass

  logger.debug("no model exists for model %s, creating one" % model_name)
  class Meta:
      db_table = table_name
      managed = False

  attrs = {
     'field1' : models.CharField(max_length=200),
     'field2' : models.CharField(max_length=200),
     'field3' : models.CharField(max_length=200)
     '__module__': 'myapp.models',
     'Meta':Meta
  }

  model = type(str(model_name), (models.Model,), attrs)
  return model
  ```
- Note that I do check if the model is already registered in django and I'm using an existing model in case it does. The model name is always unique for each table. Since I'm using multi tenants, the tenant name is also part of the model name to avoid conflict with similar tables declared on different schemas.
- In case it's not clear: the tables created dynamically will and should be persisted permanently for future sessions.

This solution works fine for me so far. 
However, the application will need to support a large number of these tables. i.e. 10,000 - 100,000 such tables(and corresponding model classes), with up to a million rows per table.
 
Assuming the underlying db is fine with this load, my questions are:

- Do you see any problem with this solution, with and without regards to the expected scale ?
- Anybody has a better solution for this scenario ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with [ContentTypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am, briefly. But I don't see how it helps in creating models during runtime. Though, it may help in replacing the way I am retrieving an existing model in case it has already been registered.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a wiki page on creating models dynamically, although it has been a while since it was last updated:

[DynamicModels Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels)

There are also a few apps that are designed for this use case, but I don't think any of them is being actively maintained:

[Django Packages: Dynamic models](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/dynamic-models/)

I understand that if you are already committed to Django this isn't very helpful, but this a use case for which Django isn't really good. It might be more costly to fight against the abstractions provided by Django's model layer, than to just use psycopg2 or whatever other adapter is appropriate for your data.

Depending on what sort of operations you are going to perform on your data, it may be also more reasonable to use a single model with an indexed field that allows you to distinguish in which table that row would be and then sharding the data by that column.

If you still need to do this, the general idea would be:

1. Create a metaclass that extends Django's ModelBase. This metaclass you would use as a factory for your actual models.
2. Consider stuff mentioned on that wiki page, like circumventing the app_label issue.
3. Generate and execute the sql for the creation of the model as also shown on the wiki page.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tomas. The packages, as you mentioned are not maintained so I prefer not to use them. The wiki page is basically what I based my approach on and indeed my next step is to follow it more closely as you suggested. Sharding is also an interesting idea, but I don't need it currently and seems to be an overkill to do that just because Django doesn't easily  support dynamic modeling.