# Printing multiple items using serializer

Tags: python, django

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def selected_device(request,pk=None):
    if pk != None:
        devices = Device.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        devicedetail = DeviceDetail.objects.filter(DD2DKEY=pk)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        tablename= "dev_interface_" + str(pk)
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT interface FROM {tablename} ")
        righttable = cursor.fetchall()
        devserializer = DeviceSerializers(devices, many=True)
        devdserializer = DeviceDetailSerializers(devicedetail, many=True)
        interfaces = []
        for i in righttable:
            interfaces.append(i[0])            
        for i in interfaces: 
                data =[{"interface": i}]  
        interserializer = InterfaceSerializers(data, many = True)
        results = {
            "device":devserializer.data,
            "device_details" : devdserializer.data,
            "interface":interserializer.data,
        }
        return Response(results)
```

In `interfaces`, I have the following `['G0/1', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/1/5', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/1/20', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/1/21', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/1/22', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/1/23', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/1/24', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/1/25', 'TenGigabitEthernet1/1/26']`
But the above codes just print the last item in `interface`, how do I ensure it to print everything in interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write

```
for i in interfaces:
    data = [{"interface": i}]
```

which means you keep on overwriting `data` with a new value.  I *think* you want:

```
data = []
for i in interfaces:
    data.append({"interface": i})
```

or more simply

```
data = [{"interace": i} for i in interfaces]
```