# Dynamic Models at Runtime Django 1.8

Tags: django, mongodb, postgresql, dynamic, django-models

I'm using Django 1.8.4 and Python 3.4.3, and I want to be able to create models through a form either on the main app or the admin page.

It subclasses my own predefined model and must also be able to have static variables.

I've been trying to research this for awhile and have encountered a lot of documentation on the creation of the model but I can't find how I would actually migrate the information.

So far I've been looking at the type() and have considered the possibility of using inspectdb, or even MongoDB but I've mainly used PostgreSQL.

If anyone could give insight on whether it would be possible to manually migrate the information or how to actually register the models to a postgres database it would be much appreciated.

I was actually following this as well:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/442/

However I was confused as to what module stood for in the create_model function and how to use migrate_table_structure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this previous answer?

[Django dynamic model fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/)

It's a bit of an old one, but I think the content there could be relevant to your question. If not, could you elaborate on why it doesn't address your problem?

Comment: I've looked at these and while they were helpful they're a little old. The support isn't there for non-South migrations that are used in Django 1.8 from what I could telll.