# Temporary models in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

In one celery task I need to create temporary table in database. In [this article](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/04/13/temporary-models-django/) Daniel Roseman explained how to create one. But this solution does not work in Django 1.9. I tried to look into Django docs and Google but I was unable to find anything useful.

Code from mentioned article which worked in Django 1.8:

```
from django.db import models, cursor
from django.contrib.contenttypes.management import update_contenttypes
from django.core.management import call_command

class TempCustomerAddress(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Address')
    legacy_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'utils'


class Command(NoArgsCommand):

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        models.register_models('utils', TempCustomerAddress)
        models.signals.post_syncdb.disconnect(update_contenttypes)
        call_command('syncdb')

        # ... do importing and stuff referring to TempCustomerAddress ...

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('DROP TABLE `utils_tempcustomeraddress`')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In django 1.9 you actually don't need to register anything. You just create model the same way as in `models.py` and that's it. You only need to make sure that it is not in `models.py` file because than it will be permanent model.
This example assumes that you already ran all migrations.

```
from django.db import models, cursor
from django.contrib.contenttypes.management import update_contenttypes
from django.core.management import call_command

class TempCustomerAddress(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Address')
    legacy_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'utils'


class Command(NoArgsCommand):

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS utils_tempcustomeraddress')
            cursor.execute('''
                CREATE TABLE utils_tempcustomeraddress (
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                    address_id REFERENCES accounts_address (id),
                    legacy_id VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE
                );
            '''
            # ... do importing and stuff referring to TempCustomerAddress ...

            cursor.execute('DROP TABLE `utils_tempcustomeraddress`')
```

Comment: The imports are not correct. It should be just `from django.db import models, connection` and nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to create a temporary model derived from a "permanent" model, and use temporary table storage to avoid polluting the tables of the permanent one. After a lot of poking around including an article relating to [Django 0.96](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels), some newer material it points to for [Django 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/7934577#7934577) and some [old material](https://github.com/willhardy/dynamic-models) based on migration tech integrated into Django I finally came up with a recipe that works with Django 2.0.

First, I needed to explicitly specify the database table name using the Meta:

```
model_name = re.sub('[@.]', '_', 'some_string')

class Meta:
    app_label = original_model._meta.app_label
    #
    # Use the explicit name for the database table.
    #
    db_table = '"' + model_name.lower() + '"'
```

Then I created the Model class by copying what I needed from the original:

```
attr = {'__module__': __name__, 'Meta': Meta}
local_fields = [field.name for field in original_model._meta.local_fields]
for field in original_model._meta.fields:
    #
    # Clone only the fields which we need, not forgetting that we only
    # want one primary key.
    #
    clone = field.clone()
    if field.name in local_fields:
        local_fields.remove(field.name)
    else:
        clone.primary_key = False
    if not isinstance(field, (db_models.AutoField, db_models.OneToOneField, db_models.ManyToManyField)):
        attr[field.name] = clone
new_model = type(model_name, (db_models.Model,), attr)
```

The hard part was tracking down how to create the new table for the model. Once found, the answer was simple:

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.schema_editor() as schema_editor:
    schema_editor.create_model(new_model)
```

Comment: I should say that cloning a field using deepcopy() is not a complete solution...that was just an example. The deepcopy() preserves all sorts of data that ties the copied field back to the original model.

Comment: FWIW, it turns out that Field.clone() knows how to duplicate a field. Answer updated to reflect this.