# Create test-only models within an app part of a larger project

Tags: python, mysql, django, testing, sqlite

I am looking for a way to create temporary models to test a simple django app part of a larger django project.

If it was not of the models I need to test the app, I would just create a `tests/` directory within that app, however it does not work since it requires the migrations.

I'd like to avoid to:

- create a sibling test app with the tests in it
- create another application in another repository and install through pip
- pollute the database with the test models
- create the tables manually using SQL

I use both sqlite3 and MySQL. Django 1.9.5

What I tried:

1. [Create tables manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35506701/2115513)
2. [Django Fake Models](https://github.com/erm0l0v/django-fake-model) does not seem to work

Comment: I know you want to avoid creating a new sibling test app, but I don't think of any other way. In case someone's also looking for this, there's this similar _older question_: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502916/django-how-to-create-a-model-dynamically-just-for-testing The top voted solutions don't work anymore but these two answers should work in more recent django versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8719352/1092815 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34900947/1092815 In other words I would load the sibling app only when testing (using environment variables or `if 'test' in sys.argv`).