# Is it possible to create django models from csv in the view?

Tags: django, django-models

> So this might be a weird or super easy question. Is it possible to
>   build a table(model like) from csv files on the go from django views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Models are ultimately just Python classes, so, Yes, you can create then at runtime.

There are two excellent sources that come to mind:

- [Dynamic Models — from the Django Wiki](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels)
- Answer to ["Django dynamic model fields" — here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/7934577#7934577)

They cover pretty much all you need.