# Convert JSON data into structured data in an SQL database using Django ORM

Tags: python, django, database-design

I am building a chatbot using Django with a MySQL backend. 
I have a `ChatSession` model which represents all the useful information to be stored after the end of a chat session .

Now, it has a JSON field called `cc_data`(Implemented using [`django-jsonfield`](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield))

Here's an example of the content of that field:

```
{
  "slots":{
    "chal_tech":"What is the Proof",
    "nats":["I will fail the course","Nobody likes me"],
    "distortion":"Jumping to Conclusions",
    "user_name":"parth",
  }
}
```

I recently realized that I need to query for some fields in this `slots` dictionary. An example query would be to list out all the `nats` in the last 10 chat sessions.

It seems that reading all the values of the JSONs into dicts and then searching/manipulating them would be inefficient.Therefore I sought to convert this JSON representation into Django ORM models(SQL).

However, while trying to do this I ran into a problem. The "keys" of the `slots` dictionary are probably finite in number, but I don't know exactly how many of them will be required at this point. In any case, it would be a large number (around 50-100).

- Manually writing the model classes for so many attributes in `models.py` seems inefficient and also a bit repetitive (Most of them would simply have a single `JSONfield` or `TextField`). Even with abstract models I would still have to list out classes for all the "keys" in the `models.py` file.
- Ideally I'd like to generate model classes for any new "keys" automatically and on the fly. I did look at [dynamic models in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/7934577#7934577) but none of the solutions really seem efficient. The host I am using doesn't support NoSQL so I can't use that solution.

How do I convert this into valid a valid Django ORM/SQL design so that the queries are efficient and the code isn't repetitive ?

Comment: Either pick a [Entity-Attribute-Value solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) for Django, or use PostgreSQL and [query against Django's JSON field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield)

Comment: Why do you want to generate a new model for a new key? Would not a model with object FK, kind (slot name) and content (whatever you prefer, text or json) be sufficient?

Comment: @awesoon That's what I was thinking of doing. However, there is a slight caveat, if content of the slot is JSON itself and I need to search for keys inside that, then I run into the same problem again.