# Django - Show only a specific dynamic fields per models in django-eav2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to figure it out on how I can show only a specific set of dynamic fields in **eav** to a unique registered model in my apps.models. But I don't know how to this, I've also read the documents but I can't seem to find anything about it, or maybe I've come across it and didn't understand.

Now, what is happening is that, when I add an **attribute** in the django admin. It also adds the dynamic field in all the models registered in the **eav**.

What I want to do is that;

- **model 1** - dynamic_field1, dynamic_field2, dynamic_field3
- **model 2** - dynamic_field4, dynamic_field5, dynamic_field6

Btw, I'm currently using the django-eav2 the documentation is in the [link](https://django-eav-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). I've found my solution for my initial use case here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields)

Below codes are basically on how to register my models to the **eav**. Here is my sample models

```
class ClientName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class CallDetails(models.Model):
    client_name = models.ForeignKey(ClientName, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    letter_info = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.client_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Call Detail'
        ordering = ['client_name']


eav.register(ClientName)
eav.register(CallDetails)
```

below is my admin.py

```
class CallDetailsAdminForm(BaseDynamicEntityForm):
    model = CallDetails


class CallDetailsAdmin(BaseEntityAdmin):
    form = CallDetailsAdminForm

admin.site.register(CallDetails, CallDetailsAdmin)
```