# How can I solve a construction of "planning-" and "Execution"-Models in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

i am trying to develop a workout-tracking website with django.

the idea is, to create one view to "plan" and "create" the workout, and another view to "execute" one of the saved workouts.

**Plan-Mode**

```py
class Workout(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Excercise(models.Model):
    exercise = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sets = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    reps = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now)
    workout = models.ForeignKey(Workout, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Data could look like:

```
"Leg Workout": (workout.title)
{
  ("Squats", 5, 5, 35.5),
  ("Leg Press",3,8,55.15),
}
```

this is it for the **Plan-Mode**, works fine!
and now im stuck!

the **Exe-Mode** should look like this:

```
title:Leg Workout
    exercise: Squats
        Set 1: n of 5 Reps with 35.5kg  
        Set 2: n of 5 Reps with 35.5kg
        Set 3: n of 5 Reps with 35.5kg
        Set 4: n of 5 Reps with 35.5kg
        Set 5: n of 5 Reps with 35.5kg
    exercise: Leg Press
        Set 1: n of 8 Reps with 55.15kg  
        Set 2: n of 8 Reps with 55.15kg
        Set 3: n of 8 Reps with 55.15kg
```

i dont know how to handle the sets, reps and weight attributes. i guess i'd have to create a dynamic Model (for e.g. WorkoutSession), and dynamically add attributes depending of the amount of sets defined? (like in this post [Django dynamic model fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/7934577#7934577))

any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If I understood you correctly) You could create another model called `Set`

```
class Set(models.Model):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Excercise, on_delete.models.CASCADE)
    set_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    reps = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now)
```

so you would have for example:

```
Workout model instance: Leg Workout
    Exercise model instance: Squats
        Set model instance 1:
            number: 1
            reps: 5
            weight: 35.5kg  
        Set model instance 2:
            number: 2
            reps: 7
            weight: 30kg  
        ...
```

Again, if this is what you are asking?