# Is it possible to create a dynamic form (add new fields in runtime) with CreateView in Django?

Tags: django, dynamicform

I'm building a form that allows the user to add the different features of a product, and I also want it to be a dynamic form so the user can put whatever categories he want in it. Something like,

Form:

Name: shirt

Description: ...

Categorie1: Color: Red

Categorie2: Sleeve: short

Categorie3: ...

Add new categorie

Save

The problem is that I'm using CreateView for this page and don't know how to convert my form into a dynamic one. There's a way for doing this? or it's better to make it with a function view instead of CreateView?

Here's my code,

view:

```
class ProductCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = "product_create.html"
    form_class = ProductModelForm
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="products/images/")
    price = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    categorie = models.CharField(max_lenght = 50, default = '')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("products:product-detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.image.delete()
        super().delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

form:

```
class ProductModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'image',
            'price',
            'active',
            'categorie'
            ]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, what you want to do is to pass some fields without filling them.  If this is the case, there are basically 2 ways of doing it. You can either overwrite the fields you want to be not required or overwrite the initialization of form class.

For the first case:

```
class ProductModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required=False)
    # ... follow this for all fields you want to be not required ...

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'image',
            'price',
            'active',
            'categorie'
            ]
```

For the second case:

```
class ProductModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'image',
            'price',
            'active',
            'categorie'
            ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(My_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].required = False
        # ... follow this for all fields you want to be not required ...
```

If you are having Foreign Keys in your model fields, latter solution is much better since you don't need to set `qs` attribute.

**Note that** your fields in your model should be both `blank=True` and `null=True` for these solutions to work

Comment: My problem is that I want to have each product with a list of categories (and a category is a pair key: value).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields