# Add columns in model in DJango based on if else condition

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

This is my Django code for my model
I want to have columns in the model based on the value of chart type enter column there`

```
class DashboardCreativeQuery(models.Model):
query_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, unique=True)
query = models.TextField( null=False)
chart_type = models.ForeignKey(DashboardCreativeCharts, blank=True, null=True, related_name='chart_type',
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
if chart_type:
    test=  JSONField(null=False)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do? Would you like to create dynamic column in your database based on user input?

Comment: Yes thats right,i want to create dynamic column in your database based on user input?

Comment: Take a look to that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields) and to this [extension](https://pypi.org/project/django-dcolumns/)

Answer (score 0):

By default, django, uses a [Relational Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database). A Relational Database store data in relations:

> A relation is defined as a set of tuples that **have the same attributes**.

That means, in a relation (table) all tulles (rows) must have the same attributes (columns). For this reason, if you are using a relation (a table) to store your data, you should don't change model fields dynamically.

#### What can you do

- Take a look to django [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance-1), maybe it is a solution for you.
- Move your solution to a no-sql backend like mongo.